# Single word to express an object having the capacity to stretch a larger radius than another object?

Tags: single-word-requests

If one circular object A (such as a [hair rubber band](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=hair%20rubber&client=firefox-a&hs=ybP&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=B4VqUpTdEM_xhQeTtID4CQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=555)) has the same radius at rest as another B, but stretches to a larger radius than B is able to, is there a way to say "A is xxxxxer than B"?

Comment: Not that I know of. "A has a larger radius than B", or "A's radius is larger than B's" (or something like that) is the only way, I think.

Comment: Usually, it's just *larger*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, in the rubber band example it's not really larger at all, as both objects have the same mass etc (they are also homeomorphic) .It's just that one sort of extends more in space.

Comment: Oh, you mean *stretches to a larger radius*?

Comment: If a circle, you can simply say *larger*. A larger circle has a larger radius, circumference, diameter, and area, all in strict ratio to each other. If it is larger, it is larger.

Comment: @AndrewLeach precisely

Comment: One further clarification: are you after a word for the *capability* of being stretched to a larger radius, or for *actually being stretched* to that larger radius? In other words, when A is at rest, and thus the same size and shape as B, does A still exhibit this property that you are looking for?

Comment: @JohnY I mean the actual state. If A is at rest it does not exhibit the property.

Comment: I think the rubber band example might be overcomplicating things, but I'm not certain. If you had some other round things that did not stretch, like plates, and one had a larger radius than the other, would the word you're looking for still apply?

Comment: @DCShannon Alas, 2 years and 2 days later I don't remember at all what I had in mind then. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If *you* don't even know what you were asking I would close or delete the question.

Comment: Whether this question should be closed is [being discussed in Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/why-was-my-flag-declined-and-can-we-close-this-question/7269?noredirect=1#comment28739_7269).

Answer (score 3):

Typically, round objects are sized when at rest. (See [Amazon's listings for rubber bands](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=rubber%20bands&sprefix=rubbe%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Arubber%20bands) as an example.)

To describe an object that *expands* to a greater radius you would say it has more **elasticity** or better/larger **expansion**. This works best when comparing two objects with the same resting size:

> Objects A and B are 2.5cm wide but B has more elasticity.

If you need to compare two objects with different resting sizes or need to explicitly note the maximum expansion size you would just use "expands to":

> Object A is 2.5cm wide and expands to 4.5cm. Object B is 2cm wide and expands to 5cm.

If you only want to describe which has a larger size once expanded use "expansion", which keys on the definition of "the degree, extent, or amount by which something expands"

> Object A has a larger expansion than Object B.

Comment: A slightly-informal way to say "has more elasticity" in a single word is *stretchier*.

Comment: *More elasticity* is incorrect here. More elasticity means more capability of returning to the original shape/size. It does not mean better/larger expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any *single* word that serves the role you're asking (taking on *-er*); the closest is probably to say *more [whatever]*, such as more **elastic**, **stretchable**, or **expandable**.

*Edit, to take into account comment about actual state, rather than potential:* Again, I can't think of an existing word that would take *-er* and mean what you are looking for. The closest phrasing I can think of with as few words as possible is "A is **hyperexpanded** relative to B".

I'm not just coining *hyperexpanded* myself; this word is commonly used to refer to lungs which have expanded beyond normal size. Some care might be needed when using this word with your circular bands, because there is the connotation of abnormality or damage. If I hear someone talking about a hyperexpanded rubber band, I'm going to think the band can't return to its original (undamaged) rest size on its own. That's why I included "relative to B". Still doesn't feel exactly right, but nothing better is coming to me.

Comment: You are more correct that hyperexpanded would mean "expanded beyond a safe limit" than it would help note that one thing is greater than another when expanded.

Comment: *More elastic* is incorrect here. More elastic means more capable of returning to the original shape/size. It does not mean more stretchable/expandable.

Comment: @Drew: In strict physics terms, you are correct. But in everyday lay speech, *elastic* strongly implies both the stretching and the returning. If something very readily returns to its shape but does not readily stretch, most people don't think of that as *elastic*, even though strictly it is. Likewise, if something is readily compressible or otherwise deformable, but not readily stretchable, most people don't think of that as *elastic* either. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elastic) lists your definition first (1a) but most people think of definition 3.

Comment: @JohnY: Maybe so. But even if true, that doesn't imply that *more elastic* means stretchable to a greater extent. One might claim that it means more "**readily** stretchable" (whatever that might mean). The 3rd definition you cite does not suggest anything about the extent of expansion. It speaks only to the ability to be "**easily** stretched or expanded".

Comment: @Drew: Lay people do not think or talk like physicists. When normal people hear "more readily stretchable", they may well think either or both of "more easily stretchable" or "stretchable to a greater extent". And indeed, for a lot of real-world substances that lay people are likely to encounter in their daily lives, these properties are correlated anyway. The distinction is all the more fuzzy if you simply use the phrase "more stretchable", which you seem to be saying is what should be used instead of "more elastic". But *elastic* and *stretchable* are basically synonymous in lay speech.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to get at what you are asking without more context, but for rubber bands, the two main properties people are interested in are elasticity and stretchability.

When stretched there is an "elastic limit" beyond which they will not return to their original shape, and further beyond that is a measurement of "tensile strength" where they break.

I would expect these limits to be described in terms of force rather than radius, but for a catalog etc. it may suffice to simply say "higher stretchability" or make up a term like "stretchability index of 4 inches" etc etc